# How do I find the return type of a method with System.Reflection.MethodBase in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, postsharp

how do I find out the return type of a method from the MethodBase? I'm using PostSharp and trying to override the CompileTimeValidate(MethodBase method) method to make sure the attribute is applied to a method with the correct signature.

Thanks,

Answer (score 23, accepted):

MethodBase is used as a base class of [MethodInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.aspx) which has a property [ReturnType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.returntype.aspx).

You could try and cast to an instance of MethodInfo and check that property.

Comment: What if we want to find it from MemberInfo. Assume this scenario that we want to filter all the members, like methods and fields that are/returning string type. Does MemberInfo has any property to indicate that?

Answer (score 23):

`MethodBase` itself does not have a return type because in addition to normal methods it also is used to represent methods, such as constructors, which have no return type.  Instead you need to see if it's an instance of `MethodInfo` and check that for the `ReturnType` property.

```
CompileTimeValidate(MethodBase method) {
  var normalMethod = method as MethodInfo;
  if( normalMethod != null) {
    ValidateReturnType(normalMethod.ReturnType);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this. `MethodInfo` has the property but `MethodBase` is used for constructors as well, and they do not have a return type.

```
MethodBase b = this.GetType().GetMethods().First(); 
if(b is MethodInfo)
    MessageBox.Show((b as MethodInfo).ReturnType.Name);
```

Comment: Minor point...if you're already checking `b is MethodInfo`, then a direct cast `(MethodInfo)b` is slightly preferable to `b as MethodInfo`.

Comment: The guideline I follow: Use `as` when receiving a null (for an incompatible type) is acceptable to your code. In this case, since a null is *not* acceptable inside the if, use `(MethodInfo)b` instead. Better yet, avoid the cost of doing the cast twice by using `as` instead of `is` and testing against null.

Answer (score 0):

Try the `MethodInfo.ReturnType` property.

To get the return type property, first get the `Type`. From the `Type`, get the `MethodInfo`. From the `MethodInfo`, get the `ReturnType`.

It seems like you can't do it with MethodBase...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodinfo.returntype.aspx